# What tables make up a ModX resource

Tags: mysql, modx, modx-revolution

I know that `site_content` is the main one. Are there any related tables required for ModX Resources?

Answer (score 0):

`site_tmplvar_contentvalues` - for storing tv values. These two tables - all you need in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

To get a real understanding of how modx works you'll need to do a little research into [xPDO](http://rtfm.modx.com/xpdo/2.x/). More specifically the [xPDO](http://rtfm.modx.com/xpdo/2.x/) schema.

Check out the modx schema on [git](https://github.com/modxcms/revolution/blob/master/core/model/schema/modx.mysql.schema.xml#L950)